# Is there an extension like StartWith but for the end of an observable sequence?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I want to append an extra "closing" item to my observable sequence. Is there a Reactive LINQ extension that is like `StartWith` but for the end of an observable sequence?

Here is an approximation of what I want, although it doesn't seem to fire the last element:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> EndWith<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TSource element)
{
    return source.Concat(Observable.Return(element));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'approximation' is the correct answer. `Concat` will add `element` to the end of your source stream, but only if:

1. Source completes
2. Source does not error

Perhaps if you aren't getting it, your `source` stream isn't actually terminating?

It might be better if you show us more of your code etc.
There isn't an 'out of the box' API method (like `StartsWith`) that does this for you, but using `Concat` + `Observable.Return` is a pretty reasonable way to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Turns out I was using a `CombineLatest` where I should have used `WithLatestFrom`. This lead to a subtle bug where my observables weren't closing.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) package [contains](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable) the non-standard `Append` and `Prepend` operators.

```
// Append a value to an observable sequence.
public static IObservable<TSource> Append<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TSource value);

// Prepend a value to an observable sequence.
public static IObservable<TSource> Prepend<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TSource value);
```